# Текст заезжает за края

Tags: css

Как пофиксить заезд текста за края? `overflow: hidden`. `padding` не помог.

[image]

```
<v-card
        class="custom-debug d-flex"
        style="overflow: hidden; padding: 30px 20px 20px 20px; margin: 0 130px 0 0"
        height="530"
        :elevation="10"
    >
        ...
            <v-card-text
                class="subtitle-1 text-justify"
                style="color: #888888"
            >
                {{ course.description }}
                {{ course.description }}
                {{ course.description }}
                {{ course.description }}
                {{ course.description }}
                {{ course.description }}
                {{ course.description }}
                {{ course.description }}
                {{ course.description }}
            </v-card-text>
...
    </v-card>
```

Проблема в том, что рамка обрезается и уезжает вниз. Это происходит из-за того, что выставлен `overflow: hidden`. Соответственно, паддинг не работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Update для

**Уберите у родителя padding: 30px 20px 20px 20px; и поставьте дочке margin: 30px 20px 20px 20px;**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Sevastopol' кажется, так лучше

Comment: Что не так с моим ответом, если он сохраняет `padding`? Какой результат вы ожидаете?

Comment: @Sevastopol' разобрался. Перенёс `overflow` из родителя в дочку и заработало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте `overflow: hidden` к `v-card-text`.

**UPD.** Обновил пример. Рамка не заезжает, отступ снизу можете регулировать через `padding` у `card`.

```css
:root {
  --pad-section: 15px;
  --bg: #e6e6e6;
}

.card {
  height: 150px;
    padding: 25px;
      background-color: var(--bg);
}

.card__description {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.card__header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding: var(--pad-section);
}

.card__text {
  margin: var(--pad-section);
  overflow: hidden;
}

p {
  margin: 1px 0;
}

p:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card__description">
    <div class="card__header">Title</div>
    <div class="card__text">
      <p>Lorem</p>
      <p>Lorem</p>
      <p>Lorem</p>
      <p>Lorem</p>
      <p>Lorem</p>
      <p>Lorem</p>
      <p>Lorem</p>
      <p>Lorem</p>
      <p>Lorem</p>
      <p>Lorem</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Sevastopol' как мне для фронта сделать минимальный воспроизводимый пример? Я же не буду сюда тащить всё vue-app?

Comment: @Sevastopol' Согласен. Окей, завтра на свежую голову попробую сделать минимально воспроизводимый пример и пофиксить. Если не получиться, открою конкурс, чтобы лучше гадалось.

Comment: Ваш ответ на работает

Comment: @hedgehogues, вот теперь мне прям стало интересно какой результат вы ожидаете получить. Кроме того, что бы текст не вылезал на `padding` родителя.

Comment: @Sevastopol' Не зашло. Ну, либо я накосячил.

Comment: @E_K см. апдейт

Comment: @Sevastopol' см. апдейт. Может, понятнее станет

Comment: @Sevastopol', будет тоже самое, что и у меня в примере. Здесь нужен внятный ответ автора на вопрос **Какой нужен результат?**

Comment: Результат нужен следующий. Внизу не должна обрезаться рамка. Сейчас, как видно обрезается. Т.е. обрезается компонент (не знаю, как правильно это назвать). Таким образом, у меня внизу должен остаться некоторый gap, который в обычной ситуации я бы регулировал с помощью padding. Теорирически, можно обрезать число символов. Но кажется, что это не самое клёвое решение и выглядит как костыль

Comment: @Sevastopol' я добавил пример выше.

Comment: @hedgehogues «Я же не буду сюда тащить всё vue-app?» — а его и не надо тащить, достаточно притащить ту вёрстку, которую vue даёт после своей работы